# Bootstrap datetimepicker does not firing change event on time change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using  only time input (Custom Formats example 3 given on this link)   http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I only wants to listen for change in time when user click up or down for hour or minute changes. I tried `change.dp`, `change` and `dp.change` but none are working

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" id="start_time"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="book_meeting[start_date]" id="book_meeting_start_date" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

```js
$("#start_time").on("change", function(e) {
  alert("helloi");
});

$("#book_meeting_start_date").on("change", function(e) {
  alert("helloi");
});

$("#book_meeting_start_date").on("change.dp", function(e) {
  alert("helloi");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching  i found it's answer.i ended up using  dp.hide which is working as expected.

```
 $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    stepping: 5,
    format: 'HH:mm'
}).on('dp.hide', function (event) {

});
```

Comment: I have same issue :((( and this workaround doesn't help for my use case. Even triggering manually change event doesn't work inside that event.